# Creating factors fails inside dplyr mutate(across) call

Tags: r, dplyr, across

Creating factor levels in a dataset with NAs works for individual columns, but I need to iterate across many more columns (all start with 'impact.') and have struck a problem inside a dplyr mutate(across)

What am I doing wrong?

Reprex below

```
library(tribble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(~id, ~tumour, ~impact.chemo, ~impact.radio,
        1,'lung',NA,1,
        2,'lung',1,NA,
        3,'lung',2,3,
        4,'meso',3,4,
        5,'lung',4,5)

# Factor labels
trt_labels <- c('Planned', 'Modified', 'Interrupted', 'Deferred', "Omitted")

# Such that factor levels match labels as, retaining NAs where present:
data.frame(level = 1:5,
           label = trt_labels)

# Create factor works for individual columns
factor(df$impact.chemo, levels = 1:5, labels = trt_labels)
factor(df$impact.radio, levels = 1:5, labels = trt_labels)

# But fails inside mutate(across)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with('impact'), ~factor(levels = 1:5, labels = trt_labels)))
```

Comment: The lambda function is not correct - you need to include `.x` or `.` for the object argument - `~factor(.x, levels = 1:5, labels = trt_labels))`.

Comment: Or you can even use `..1`, but you have to pick one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making @27ϕ9's comment an answer: the `purrr`-style lambda function you specified inside `across` is not correct because it needs the first argument, which is the object the function should refer to (in this case, the dataframe columns selected by `across`).

To fix your issue, you should insert `.x` inside the lambda function, which is non other than a shortcut for `function(x) x` - see this [page](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) for more info about `purrr`-style lambda functions.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with('impact'), ~factor(.x, levels = 1:5, labels = trt_labels)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      id tumour impact.chemo impact.radio
#   <dbl> <chr>  <fct>        <fct>       
# 1     1 lung   NA           Planned     
# 2     2 lung   Planned      NA          
# 3     3 lung   Modified     Interrupted 
# 4     4 meso   Interrupted  Deferred    
# 5     5 lung   Deferred     Omitted
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks all - 27ϕ9 & Ric S solved it: adding `.x` argument fixed it.

For future users: if each column doesn't contain ≥1 of every factor level, then you need to specify factor levels (here `levels = 1:5`), such that number of observed or explicitly stated levels = number of labels.